Angular xslt conversion showing error "[object DocumentFragment]'
I have to convert the xml using the xslt in Angular. I got the result for conversion, but when I bind result to div with [innerHTML] an error of [object DocumentFragment] is appearing.
Html code is
<div class="body">
    <div class="container-fluid p-0">
    <div id="xmlcontent" [innerHTML]="xmlcontent">
    </div>
    <div id="htmlcontent" [innerHTML]="htmlcontent">
    </div>
</div>
<button type="button" (click)="convert()">xml to html</button>
<br/>
<button type="button" (click)="getHtmlFile()">html content</button>
</div>

TS code is
export class XmlconvertComponent implements OnInit {
  _httpClient!: HttpClient;
  xmlcontent:any;
  htmlcontent: any;
  sanitizer!: DomSanitizer;
  convert() {
    const xml = this.loadXMLDoc("assets/xml/test.xml");
    const xsl = this.loadXMLDoc("assets/xml/test.xsl");
    const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
    const resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml, document);
//document.getElementById("xmlcontent")?.appendChild(resultDocument);
    this.xmlcontent=resultDocument;
  }
  constructor(_httpClient: HttpClient) { 

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  loadXMLDoc(filename: any): any {
    const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
    try { xhttp.responseType = 'document' } catch (err) { } // Helping IE11
    xhttp.send("");
    return xhttp.responseXML;
  }

  getHtmlFile() {
    let path = 'assets/xml/test.html';
    this._httpClient.get(path, {responseType: "text"}).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.htmlcontent = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(data);
      });
  }

Please note, when i use this code "document.getElementById("xmlcontent")?.appendChild(resultDocument);", I got the output, but when I click again the same content is repeated.
Can someone help me to display the conent in
<div id="xmlcontent" [innerHTML]="xmlcontent">
        </div>

Also one more issue i am facing in getHtmlFile() function.
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')

Can help for this issue also
These are the xml, xslt and html content files
XML file
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>

XSL file is
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
                <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
                <tr>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="title" /></td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Html content file is
<html><head><title>Test html Code</title><style>
                    body
                    {
                    font-size:12pt;
                    font-family:arial;
                    }
                    .sectiontitle, .Agtitle, .chaptertitle
                    {
                    font-size:14pt;
                    margin-top:12pt;
                    }
                   .list2
                    {
                    margin-top: 9pt;
                    margin-left: 18pt;
                    }
                </style></head><body style="font-family:arial;"><div class="Root"><div class="Ag"><p class="agtitle">3701:1 Control</p><div class="Chapter"><p class="chaptertitle">Chapter Physical Protection Program</p><div class="Section"><p class="sectiontitle">ther place of use or storage.</p><div class="subsection">(A) Procedures for submitting advance notification:<div class="list2">(1) The notification must be </div><div class="list2">(2)  facility.</div><div class="list2">(3) A notification delivered .</div></div></div></div></div></div></body></html>


You could first remove all children (either with removeChild or by simply setting textContent = '') and then appendChild that fragment that transformToFragment gives you. There is also a replaceChild method but with several child nodes like a heading and a table that might not be the right method to handle the replacement; so unless DOM level 4 has some more power method like replaceContent I would delete the contents and then appendChild the fragment

So there is a replaceChildren method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/replaceChildren in the modern DOM you could use instead of the appendChild (or the previous suggestion to first delete all children and then appendChild the fragment).

@Martin Honnen. Yes we can replace the children node, if we cant bind to innerHtml. Are you have any suggestion on "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')"

No, basically I saw your question due to the xslt tag, I don't do angular to be able to help you out on anything related to that. The only code explicitly doing get is this._httpClient.get so there I would start to look but I don't know how Angular components are set up to tell whether that line can fail.
